# Cómo se dice a la acción o acto de molestar?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Por ejemplo, la acción o acto de administrar es "administración". Cómo se diría, si existe, a la acción o acto de molestar?

Comment: Pues "molestia".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La acción y efecto de molestar es *[molestia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PZ5Xhcs)*. Notablemente, ésta es una de esas palabras que tiene dos significados complementarios, porque también significa "acción y efecto de molestar**se**", es decir: una molestia es lo que un agente causa sobre un paciente, y es también lo que el paciente experimenta.

El adjetivo *molesto* también tiene esta ambigüedad, que normalmente se resuelve por contexto.

Comment: No es por ser puntilloso, pero ya que el foro es de castellano, sepa que ahora los pronombres demostrativos no son acentuados, en la reciente revisión de la gramática de la Lengua Española por la RAE.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde correcto, aunque la mayoría aún no se adhiere a esa nueva normativa.